# I want to use i18next in the class component of my project but I have this error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

> React Hook "useTranslation" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

What should I use this for in the component class?

I want to use i18next in the class component of my project but I have this error. How can I solve this problem?

```
        const { Sider } = Layout;
        const { SubMenu } = Menu;
        
        class Sidebar extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            state = {
              collapsed: false,
              theme: "dark",
              current: "1",
            };
          };
          
          // HandleClick(lang){
          //     i18next.changeLanguage(lang)
          // }
        
          changeTheme = (value) => {
            this.setState({
              theme: value ? "dark" : "light",
            });
          };
        
          onCollapse = (collapsed) => {
            console.log(collapsed);
            this.setState({ collapsed });
          };
        
          render() {
            const { collapsed } = this.state;
            const { t, i18n: instance } = useTranslation();
        
            return (
              <Sider
                collapsible
                collapsed={collapsed}
                onCollapse={this.onCollapse}
                width={256}
                theme={this.state.theme}
              >
                <div className="Logo">
                  <img src="/image/User_icon.png" style={{ width: 80, height: 90 }} />
                </div>
                <div className="switch">
                  <Switch
                    checked={this.state.theme === "dark"}
                    onChange={this.changeTheme}
                    checkedChildren="Dark"
                    unCheckedChildren="Light"
                  />
                </div>
                <Menu
                  theme="dark"
                  defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
                  mode="inline"
                  style={{ paddingTop: 60 }}
                  theme={this.state.theme}
                >
                  <SubMenu
                    style={{ lineHeight: 8 }}
                    key="sub1"
                    icon={<MailOutlined />}
                    title={t("infomationbase.InformationBase")}
                  >
                    <Menu.Item key="11">{t("infomationbase.EmPmlnspection")}</Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="12">{t("infomationbase.Setting FTP")}</Menu.Item>
                  </SubMenu>  
   </Menu>
      </Sider>

)
};

 export defulte Navbar;
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to check out the official react-i18next example: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use the `withTranslation` HOC:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

class YourClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
     const { t } = this.props;
 
     return ( <div>{t("infomationbase.EmPmlnspection")}</div>
  }
}

export default withTranslation(YourClassComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

class YourClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
     const { t } = this.props;
 
     return ( <div>{t("infomationbase.EmPmlnspection")}</div>
  }
}
```

What done above is correct just replace the export from

```
export default withTranslation(YourClassComponent);
```

to

```
export default withTranslation()(YourClassComponent);
```